# How to run concurrent, isolated instances of headless chromedriver with selenium on linux with python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use headless Chrome on a Centos 7 EC2 instance, to log into my Facebook, perform some simple actions, and quit after a few days.

I have this working properly, but if I try to run the program from two putty windows at the same time, some stage of the process fails.

The second webdriver instance either fails to load the login page or loses access to the browser once the first window's script has called driver.quit()

They appear to share a browser "window" and Facebook session data despite being run separately.

Is there a way for me to run isolated selenium/chromedriver instances?

Putty session 1:

```
py3 main.py
Platform identified as linux.  Instantiating driver...
Webdriver instantiated.
Attempting to load https://www.facebook.com/ ...
Loaded Facebook login page!
Logging in...
Attempting to load <url>
Loaded auction page!
Bid condition triggered.
Preparing to bid 3950
Submitting bid of 3950
DOM updated while attempting to bid - bid skipped, iteration continues
DOM updated while attempting to bid - bid skipped, iteration continues
Quitting webdriver...
Complete.
```

Putty session 2:

```
py3 main.py
Platform identified as linux.  Instantiating driver...
Webdriver instantiated.
Attempting to load https://www.facebook.com/ ...
Already logged in.
Attempting to load <url>
Loaded auction page!
NoSuchWindowException('no such window: window was already closed\n  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.100)', None, None)
Quitting webdriver...
Complete.
```

Comment: are you using the same credentials in both sessions?  if so, that's your problem

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I am (and this is necessary for the task the program is performing).

Why does this cause a problem?  I can accept that the user session data is shared, but that doesn't explain why running multiple selenium instances/scripts results in a single ChromeDriver instance or whether it's possible to run isolated instances.